# Facebook and sharing

Tags: javascript, facebook

how to share some link with description? I found the way of passing title&url through meta-tags, but what about a short description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean Open Graph meta tags? `description` is a meta tag just like `title` and `url`.

```
<meta property="og:description"
          content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
                   a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
                   threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
                   weapons."/>
```

[Open Graph Protocol documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [facebook ui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/):

Here is example:

```
function share() {
    url = "http://some.url.com";
    FB.ui({
        method: 'stream.publish',
        message : '',
        display: 'popup',
        attachment: {
            name: 'some title',
            href: url,
            description: 'Some description',
            media: [{'type':'image', 'src': "http://some.site.com/link/to/thumbail.jpg", href: url }]
        },
        user_message_prompt: ''
       }
    );
}
```